# Why is lando often giving me "Install of vendor/package failed?

Tags: drupal, lando

I'm on Mac and often getting a `Install of vendor/package failed` message. This can be just drupal/core or several drupal modules. `lando composer install` output includes some of these lines:

```
- Installing vardot/varbase (9.0.8): Extracting archive
  22/452 [=>--------------------------]   4%    Skipped installation of bin Resources/bin/var-dump-server for package symfony/var-dumper: name conflicts with an existing file
  29/452 [=>--------------------------]   6%    Skipped installation of bin scripts/release for package consolidation/self-update: name conflicts with an existing file
  34/452 [==>-------------------------]   7%    Skipped installation of bin bin/generate-defuse-key for package defuse/php-encryption: name conflicts with an existing file
  67/452 [====>-----------------------]  14%    Skipped installation of bin bin/generate-deps-for-config-factory for package laminas/laminas-servicemanager: name conflicts with an existing file
    Skipped installation of bin bin/generate-factory-for-class for package laminas/laminas-servicemanager: name conflicts with an existing file
 155/452 [=========>------------------]  34%    Skipped installation of bin bin/simple-phpunit for package symfony/phpunit-bridge: name conflicts with an existing file
 195/452 [============>---------------]  43%    Skipped installation of bin bin/validate-json for package justinrainbow/json-schema: name conflicts with an existing file
 205/452 [============>---------------]  45%    Skipped installation of bin bin/jsonlint for package seld/jsonlint: name conflicts with an existing file
 212/452 [=============>--------------]  46%    Skipped installation of bin security-checker for package enlightn/security-checker: name conflicts with an existing file
 225/452 [=============>--------------]  49%    Skipped installation of bin bin/psysh for package psy/psysh: name conflicts with an existing file
 229/452 [==============>-------------]  50%    Skipped installation of bin robo for package consolidation/robo: name conflicts with an existing file
 237/452 [==============>-------------]  52%    Install of drupal/core failed
    Install of drupal/commerce failed
    Install of chi-teck/drupal-code-generator failed
    Install of drush/drush failed
    Install of drupal/devel failed
    Install of ezyang/htmlpurifier failed
    Install of drupal/entity_browser failed
    Install of elasticsearch/elasticsearch failed
    Install of ruflin/elastica failed
    Install of nodespark/des-connector failed


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /app/vendor/composer/aa54b6df/drupal-core-23b4d51/misc/icons:
```

Some suggestions I recieved on Lando Slack include checking for Docker free space [image]

and checking for permissions (all files are 644 and all directories are 755), which didn't work. Also `lando composer install -v` gives me this:

```
Executing command (CWD): rm -rf '/app/vendor/composer/2ffefe25'
    Install of drupal/core failed
Executing command (CWD): rm -rf '/app/vendor/composer/2ffefe25'
```

`lando composer install` and `lando composer install -v`  outputs are from different times. So, my question is, how do I deal with this?

Comment: You say you checked file permissions... but did you try changing the permissions?

Comment: Yes I did, all files are 644 and directories 755.

Comment: I am not sure what the `app/vendor/composer/2ffefe25` folder would be. Try deleting it (make a backup) and then running `lando composer install` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"process-timeout": 0` seems to have helped.